# Explicit matrix representation of an algebraic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This may be considered an extension of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085684/representation-of-algebraic-extensions-by-matrices) question. Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and let $p(X)\in\mathbb{F}[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be the extension of $\mathbb{F}$ by adding the roots of $p$. Can we find an explicit matrix representation of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in $\mbox{End}_\mathbb{F}\mathbb{F}_p\simeq\mbox{gl}(\mathbb{F},[\mathbb{F}_p:\mathbb{F}])$ in terms of coefficients or roots of $p(X)$? I think $[\mathbb{F}_p:\mathbb{F}]=(\deg p-1)!$ can be shown by induction, but I find it hard to establish a tractable representation similar to the well known one for $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. I am much afraid of clever things like Galois or so, and I would appreciate an answer in simpler terms. Thank you.

Comment: Two quibbles: $\mathbb{F}[X]/p(X)\mathbb{F}[X]$ is only guaranteed to contain **one** root of $p$, not necessarily all of them.  To get all the roots, you'd have to take the splitting field of $p$.  Also, $\mathbb{F}_p$ almost always denotes the finite field with $p$ elements ($\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$), so you should probably choose different notation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's right, I'll remove the F/pF part. Regarding the notations, I will wait for an algebraist to tell me how that extension is usually denoted.

Comment: Let $K$ be the splitting field of $p(x)$.  Generically, one expects that $[K:F] = \deg(f)!$, but this is not always the case.  For instance, for $p(x) = x^3 - 3x + 1 \in \mathbb{Q}$, $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$.  For larger degree extension, there are even more possibilities: a degree $4$ polynomial can have Galois group $C_4, V_4, D_8, A_4$, or $S_4$, which have orders $4, 4, 8, 12, 24$, so these are the possibilities for the degree of the splitting field.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. Sorry, what is $f$ in $\deg(f)!$? As I said, I have no idea what Gaois and other oversmart things mean, so the second part of your comment is Chinese alphabet to me. Why is $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ in your first example?

Comment: Oops, I meant $p$, not $f$.  I got the example from Ch. 4 of [Milne's Field Theory notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html), so you can look there for more details.  Basically, the splitting field of a cubic $p(x)$ is always $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \sqrt{D})$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $p$ and $D$ is the discriminant of $p$.  In this case the discriminant is $D = 81$, so $\sqrt{D} \in \mathbb{Q}$ already.

Comment: Good notes, smart words. Thanks.